# Angular MatBottomSheet pushing background image up on open

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having an issue with MatBottomSheet where once it opens, it pushed up a background image that is fixed and 100vh

I have tried several suggestions, with the most sensible one being using a custom panelClass, which sets the MatBottomSheet to fixed but I have not found a suggestion that solves the issue

```
this.bottomSheet.open(MyComponent, {
    panelClass: 'custom-bottom-sheet'
});
```

This is the code i'm using the open the bottom sheet

Has anybody else seen this issue or have any suggestions to use?

EDIT:

I have found out what is causing this. When I open the bottom sheet, the following gets added to the  tag of the page:

`class="cdk-global-scrollblock" style="left: 0px;top: -589px;"`

So the full tag looks like:

`<html lang="en" class="cdk-global-scrollblock" style="left: 0px;top: -589px;">`

Why would this be and is there a method within MatBottomSheet to stop it before I use JS to remove it?